# On a new definition of fractional derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

while studying I came across the following [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260016640_A_new_definition_of_fractional_derivative) which is a joint work from four peoples: Roshdi R Khalil, M. Al Horani H Horani, Abdelrahman Yousef, M. Sababheh with first three authors from university of Jordan.

**Note that anyone with undergraduate tools in his toolkits can easily follow what is written there is no reason to be afraid**

Let us give there definition as provided in the article.

> **Definition:**
>   For fixed  $0<\alpha<1$, and a function $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb R, a>b$. Then, f is said to be $\alpha-$differentiable at a point $t\in(a,b) $ if the following limit exists
>   $$f^{(\alpha)}(t):=\lim_{\varepsilon \to0}\frac{f(t+\varepsilon t^{1-\alpha})-f(t)}{\varepsilon }$$

This definition is intriguing since a couple of days now. And I have the following question

> **Question:** Can one provide a function which is $\alpha-$differentiable in the above sense but not differentiable in the classical sense. Is there any convenient reason why one should call this as fractional derivative rather saying derivative in the classical sense?

Here is what I did

My answer to the above question is "NO" I may be wrong as well and I may miss something.

> Assume $f$ is $\alpha-$differentiable then we have, 
>   $$f^{(\alpha)}(t):=\lim_{\varepsilon \to0}\frac{f(t+\varepsilon t^{1-\alpha})-f(t)}{\varepsilon } = t^{1-\alpha}\lim_{h \to0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h } =\color{red}{t^{1-\alpha}f'(t)}$$

this shows that $f$ is differentiable in the classical sense and we have 
$$\color{blue}{f'(t)=t^{\alpha-1}f^{(\alpha)}(t)}$$
Vice versa the differentiability in the classical sense the fractional differentiability.

This is really  artefact since IMHO one should hope such equivalence to holds true. If not **What is special with this definition.?**

On the other hand it is a bitte annoying that this definition is only valid for positive value of $t>0$

**Further remark** One of the remarkable fact with this definition is that all Classical property for derivative such as product rule, chain rule, linearity, fundamental theorem of calculus. mean value theorem..... remain true in this context which less surprising given the identification above. see all details in the article.

Does anyone has a clarification of what I probably misunderstood?

Comment: I feel like you should be able to replace $t^s$ with $|t|^s \operatorname{sgn} t$ to extend to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor that might be a more intuitive way to deal with that

Comment: I think you are correct and I think they know it too from Remark 2.1?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes but see the last sentence they assume the regularity of $f$. quote: "where $\alpha \in (n,n+1)$ and $f$ is n+1-differentiable. " this is the backward implication not the forwards as I did above here

Comment: Their language is not precisely clear, if you bracket the words as follows: "one can easily show that [$f^\alpha = t^{1-\alpha} f^{(1)}$, where $\alpha \in (0,1]$ ] [and $f$ is diff. at $t>0$]." then it is your statement. Although if true, why they would write a paper about $x^s \frac{d}{dx}$ if they knew, is confusing me.

Comment: @CalvinKhor welcome to confusion Lol. I had similar problem I fell like the whole paper is only about $x^s \frac{d}{dx}$ then why not something more genral like $\phi(x) \frac{d}{dx}$????

Comment: There's a large number of citations, but I really don't think you're wrong...

Comment: Yes that is why I read the article $262$ citation that is quite allot

Comment: I found another "new derivative" $D^\alpha f := \alpha f' + (1-\alpha) f$ https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316643293_A_new_fractional_derivative_and_its_fractional_integral_with_some_example